# Sending a custom dimension to Google Analytics using the Google Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am currently trying to send a hit to Google Analytics from my CRM. I have been successful in sending events and purchase as well as products etc. However, when I try to send through a custom dimension I am not seeing this dimension within the user explorer section of Google Analytics.

My example case as follows:

1. I go to the Google Analytics Hit builder to build a prototype hit for this interaction found [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)
2. I send through an event to Analytics as follows; this contains the all important custom dimension:

```html
v   = 1
t   = event
tid = {{Analytics account ID}}
cid = {{Random string}}
ec  = Offline sales
ea  = Completed sale
el  = Oflline sale completed
ni  = 1
cd4 = Sale made
```

(Don't run the above, you need to enter it into the respective fields in the hit builder)

3. I validate this hit and as you can see below it will show valid and will send

[Image of valid hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9hOv.jpg)

4. The event shows up in the real time events
5. However, the custom dimension never shows up in Analytic's user explorer

Could someone please assist?

Comment: Did you added the Custom Dimension in the GA-Interface?

Comment: The dimension that I'm sending is non-interactional so it basically sent after the fact. What happens is someone starts a quote on our website, they don't complete, we call them back and if they do complete offline we want to pass back a dimension for the final outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically mention the user explorer report my educated guess would be that your custom dimension is not user scope (which is the only scope the user explorer will show).

Look if you can select them as secondary dimension in your standard reports or build a custom report (or rather more straightforward, check the scope of your dimension in the property settings)

Comment: Hi, I have checked this out and they were both on User scope already. It seems that sending this dimension after the fact through the Measurement protocol is a bit of an issue.